# What Channel handlers to use to send custom Java objects via Netty 4?

Tags: java, netty, nio

So, I am just getting started with Netty 4, and I am trying to pass a message from a client to the server and back.

I had initially tried sending only `String`s and my server's `initChannel()` method was defined as below:

```
public class Initializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ch.pipeline().addLast("stringEncoder", new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
        ch.pipeline().addLast("stringDecoder", new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
        ch.pipeline().addLast("chatHandler", new Handler());
    }
}
```

The `Handler` class contains the `channelRead()` etc. event-handlers.

Now, I want to extend this so as to send custom objects, instead of `String`s. In that case, what should be the best way to go about it? What encoders and decoders in netty can I use to extend them to achieve my purpose? Ideally, what I should be looking for are `ChannelHandler`s that can convert from custom object type to `ByteBuf` and vice-versa, right? Or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use your own decoder/encoder implementation for that. Alternative you could use either the protobuf support or the codec that uses java serialization / jboss marshalling for that.